# How can I connect PHP 5.1 to Oracle 7?

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I have been able to query newer Oracle databases using the PHP oci8 extension with the Oracle 10.2 Instant Client.  Unfortunately, the Oracle Instant Client seems to be unable to connect to an Oracle 7 database (version 7.3.3 to be precise).

Is there a way to query an older Oracle database from PHP?

Comment: 4 full rev's ago?  Probably out of luck.

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: @Pekka - Something about it being an unsupported version.

Comment: That's not surprising.  It may be entirely insane, but maybe Oracle 7 can be connected to via ODBC?

Comment: [This article](http://sysadmin.warp3r.com/blog/content/redhat-5-php-5-oci8-oracle-7) gives a patch against the oci8 extension to make it working with Oracle 7